# Translation Animations of multiple images in my layout getting cutoff in my android app

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I have 3 `horizontal linear layouts` of cards in my app.
4 cards in first row
a deck in the middle row
4 cards in the 3rd row.
I am just trying to **animate** the **movement** of the cards to the deck (middle layout)
I am using Translation `Animation` to move them `vertically` and `horizontally`.

The animation runs ok, but the images (they are buttons) get cutoff when trying to move outside of there own `linearlayout`.
I tried wrapping the Entire layout in a `FrameLayout`, but that did not help.
Please help.
I have my `xml layout` and code snippet below
Thank you

layout:

```
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
>     

<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

>    


<LinearLayout 
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout 
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<Button android:id="@+id/cpu1" 
android:background="@drawable/card"
android:layout_width="60dp" 
android:layout_height="79dp"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
/> 

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cpu1count"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="5"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:src="@drawable/card"
    >

</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/blankc1"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:src="@drawable/card"
    >

</ImageView>

    <LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<Button android:id="@+id/cpu2" 
android:background="@drawable/card"
android:layout_width="60dp" 
android:layout_height="79dp"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
 /> 
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/cpu2count"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="5"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:src="@drawable/card"
    >

</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/blankc2"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:src="@drawable/card"
    >

</ImageView>

    <LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<Button android:id="@+id/cpu3"
android:background="@drawable/card"
    android:layout_width="60dp" 
android:layout_height="79dp"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
 />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cpu3count"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="5"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:src="@drawable/card"
    >

</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/blankc3"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:src="@drawable/card"
    >

</ImageView>


    <LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<Button android:id="@+id/cpu4"
android:background="@drawable/card"
   android:layout_width="60dp" 
android:layout_height="79dp"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
 />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cpu4count"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="5"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:src="@drawable/card"
    >

</TextView>
     </LinearLayout>
     <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/lock14"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:src="@drawable/card"
    >

</ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <Button android:id="@+id/pile1" 
    android:background="@drawable/card"
android:layout_width="60dp" 
android:layout_height="79dp"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
/> 
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/lock14"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:src="@drawable/card"
    >

</ImageView>



<Button android:id="@+id/pile2" 
android:background="@drawable/card"
android:layout_width="60dp" 
android:layout_height="79dp"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
 /> 
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/lock15"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:src="@drawable/card"
    >

</ImageView>


</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button android:id="@+id/player1" 
    android:background="@drawable/card"
android:layout_width="60dp" 
android:layout_height="79dp"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
/> 
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/p1count"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="5"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:src="@drawable/card"
    >

</TextView>
     </LinearLayout>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/lock27"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:src="@drawable/card"
    >

</ImageView>


<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<Button android:id="@+id/player2" 
android:background="@drawable/card"
android:layout_width="60dp" 
android:layout_height="79dp"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
 /> 
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/p2count"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="5"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:src="@drawable/card"
    >

</TextView>
     </LinearLayout>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/lock28"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:src="@drawable/card"
    >

</ImageView>

    <LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<Button android:id="@+id/player3"
android:background="@drawable/card"
    android:layout_width="60dp" 
android:layout_height="79dp"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
 />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/p3count"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="5"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:src="@drawable/card"
    >

</TextView>
     </LinearLayout>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/lock29"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:src="@drawable/card"
    >

</ImageView>

<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<Button android:id="@+id/player4"
android:background="@drawable/card"
   android:layout_width="60dp" 
android:layout_height="79dp"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
 />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/p4count"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="5"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:src="@drawable/card"
    >

</TextView>
     </LinearLayout>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/lock30"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:src="@drawable/card"
    >

</ImageView>


</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then I animate each button in code (cpu1, first card in top row shown):

```
public void animate_c1_2(){

    //animates player card#1 going to deck
            cpu1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //FrameLayout cardimageblank = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.graphics_holder);
            Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 200,0, 50);   

         animation.setDuration(500);
         animation.setFillEnabled(true);
         animation.setFillAfter(true);
         cpu1.startAnimation(animation);

         animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener()         {   
               public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) { 
                   // set image resource to card value 
                   animation.setFillAfter(false);
                   //player1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


                   }             
               public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {         
                   // Do nothing!            
                   }              
               public void  onAnimationStart(Animation animation){                
                   // Do nothing!            
                   }         
               }); 

           } // end cpu1-2 anim
```

Comment: The problem is caused by wrapContent as the height and width in your LinearLayout.
If your using DP for the Cards why can't you use it for the LinearLayout?

Comment: The problem with using fill_parent with the height is that it will take up the whole screen for just that row of cards, the rest will get pushed down. I have tried Relative Layout also (lot more to layout) but in the end that did not work either. thx

Comment: Try using the FrameLayout as your root layout with fill parent. It should work and then you can overlap the layouts without causing undue problems